# "via app name" link not working from Facebook Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a problem making the "via app name" link working on the Facebook android app after posting a photo from my app. It works well on Facebook website from my computer but not on the Android Facebook App. It doesn't open anything.

I've filled all the settings in my Facebook App : package Name, Class Name, Hashes,  enabling Native App, DeepLinking, Website links, added a facebook page... I've tested it in live and sandbox mode. My app is still in beta test so not available on the play store yet.

On Android I got this :
[Facebook Android Photo](http://cerrutti.fr/errors/android_photo.jpg)

On website from my computer, I got this :
[Facebook Computer Photo](http://cerrutti.fr/errors/computer_photo.jpg)

I use the Facebook SDK for Unity v5.1.0 for posting photo with that API Call :

```
FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, APICallback, wwwForm);
```

If I use the FB.Feed function instead, my app opens (from Faceboook Android app) when I click on the content but not on the 'via app name' so the deep link seems to work (at least on the content)

Is there a way to make it work on the "via app name" from the Facebook Android App?